# XCTest shows results from deleted tests

Tags: xcode5, xctest

Is there any way of getting XCode to forget about XCTests that have been deleted?

To reproduce this:

1. Create failing XCTestCase
2. Delete file containing failing XCTestCase

After this, if you test the application, although it shows that all tests have passed, the failed tests still appear in the issue navigator. The removed test cases are correctly removed from the test case navigator.

A clean build doesn't resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having this problem too, it's driving me up the wall

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a bug from XCode that will be fixed in future updates.

In the meanwhile you can manually delete the test build history.

1. Close your project
2. Go to your project path on the terminal
3. Run `find . -name "*xcuserstate"|xargs rm`
4. Reopen your project

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: after installing xcode 5.0.2 today, this problem seems fixed now.